# SIGSEGV at Android boot

Tags: android, screen, boot, segmentation-fault, surfaceflinger

I recently installed (with Odin) the latest stock ROM for my SGS2 without wiping data.
After that I put a rooted kernel and started using.

I found out that:
- if I boot the phone, let it get to the lock screen (the first to appear after Samsung logo) and then turn off screen with power button, all goes fine
- if I don't turn screen off, the boot proccess goes wrong and all freeze; I can only force boot it again.

I took logcat of both boots and found these errors in the faulty one.
NB: I cut some parts of the SIGSEGV to remain within 30000 characters limit.

Can anybody help fix the problem?

Thank you!!!

```
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 51 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 51 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 51 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 51 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 52 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 52 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 52 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 52 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 53 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 53 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 53 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 53 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 54 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 54 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 54 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 54 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 55 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 55 fails, max service is 80
E/UsimServiceTable: isActive for service 55 fails, max service is 40
E/UsimServiceTable: isSSTAvailable for service 55 fails, max service is 80

E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_sys_watchdog
E/Watchdog: WATCHDOG caused by com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService

E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.DeadObjectException
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3305)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/Sensors : sensorservice died [0x4c38d570]

E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10012 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getCellLocation(ITelephony.java:1261)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getCellLocation(TelephonyManager.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at ekv.a(SourceFile:53)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at com.google.android.location.os.real.SdkSpecific8.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at ekl.handleMessage(SourceFile:187)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at eko.run(SourceFile:804)
E/AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

E/BootAnimation: sequence and loop RBG type's are different. seqeunce:7,loop:6

E/BootAnimation: /sys/class/sec/led/led_pattern: open error, fd = -1

E/SECHWC_LOG: int hwc_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**)::window_set_pos is failed : Bad address
E/SECHWC_LOG: int destroyMem(s3c_mem_t*)::invalied fd(0) fail
E/SECHWC_LOG: int hwc_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**)::destroyMem() fail
E/SurfaceFlinger: composer device failed to initialize (Invalid argument)
D/SurfaceFlinger: About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x4193cd78
F/libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00002900 (code=1), thread 4408 (SurfaceFlinger)
I/SurfaceFlinger: EventThread ready to run.
I/BootAnimation: ret=2, fps:12, interval:83333
E/BootAnimation: sequence and loop RBG type's are different. seqeunce:7,loop:6
I/BootAnimation: createSurface BGRA8888
I/ServiceManager: service 'nfc' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'iphonesubinfo' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'com.orange.authentication.simcard' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'isms' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'phoneext' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'phone' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'sip' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'simphonebook' died
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase: releaseOutput() 2
I/DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100P/GT-I9100P:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9100PXXLSK:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   : pid: 4403, tid: 4408, name: SurfaceFlinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00002900
D/dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 155 unimplemented (abstract) methods
I/DEBUG   :     r0 41953580  r1 00000001  r2 419442e8  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   :     r4 419531c0  r5 00002901  r6 00000001  r7 4193d730
I/DEBUG   :     r8 4105ecac  r9 00000001  sl 4193d72c  fp 0000000d
I/DEBUG   :     ip 401d0168  sp 4105ec60  lr 400c33bf  pc 00002900  cpsr 20000030
I/DEBUG   :     d0  3f00000000000000  d1  00000000437f0000
I/DEBUG   :     d2  437f00003f000000  d3  437f8000000000ff
I/DEBUG   :     d4  c0000000437f0000  d5  3f800000bf800000
I/DEBUG   :     d6  3f8000003f800000  d7  00ffffff3f800000
I/DEBUG   :     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d16 7fffffffffffffff  d17 7fffffffffffffff
I/DEBUG   :     d18 0000000000000000  d19 3fe0000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d20 3fe000000000946f  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   :     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : backtrace:
I/DEBUG   :     #00  pc 00002900  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   :     #01  pc 000203bd  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::HWComposer::commit() const+14)
I/DEBUG   :     #02  pc 0001fd05  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::DisplayHardware::flip(android::Region const&) const+60)
I/DEBUG   :     #03  pc 00022f8f  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onScreenReleased()+70)
I/DEBUG   :     #04  pc 00022fb9  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   :     #05  pc 00020d4b  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageBase::handleMessage(android::Message const&)+12)
I/DEBUG   :     #06  pc 000149e3  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+426)
I/DEBUG   :     #07  pc 00014b01  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
I/DEBUG   :     #08  pc 000210d9  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageQueue::waitMessage()+40)
I/DEBUG   :     #09  pc 00021991  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::threadLoop()+4)
I/DEBUG   :     #10  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
I/DEBUG   :     #11  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   :     #12  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
I/DEBUG   :     #13  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : stack:
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec20  41944370  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec24  410942d0  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so (_gles_clear+1148)
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec28  00000001  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec2c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec30  00000001  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec34  41943a10  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec38  0000ff00  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec3c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec40  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec44  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec4c  ff000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec50  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec54  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec58  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   :     #00  4105ec60  41953580  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   :     #01  4105ec60  41953580  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec64  4193db00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec68  419442e8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec6c  400c2d09  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::DisplayHardware::flip(android::Region const&) const+64)
I/DEBUG   :     #02  4105ec70  4193db00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec74  4105ecac  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec78  00000007  
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec7c  40241d00  /system/lib/libui.so
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec80  4193db00  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec84  4193cd78  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec88  400c3d3f  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::MessageBase::handleMessage(android::Message const&))
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec8c  4193d730  [heap]
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec90  40193ebe  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   :          4105ec94  400c5f93  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::onScreenReleased()+74)
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : memory near r0:
```

[.........................]

```
I/DEBUG   : 
I/DEBUG   : memory map around fault addr 00002900:
I/DEBUG   :     (no map below)
I/DEBUG   :     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   :     4000e000-4000f000 /system/lib/libstdc++.so
I/SamplingProfilerIntegration: Profiling disabled.
I/Zygote  : !@beginofpreloadClasses()
I/Zygote  : Preloading classes...
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
I/Zygote  : !@beginofpreloadResources()
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 80% free 528K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 80% free 527K/2560K, paused 10ms+0ms, total 13ms
E/installd: eof
E/installd: failed to read size
I/installd: closing connection
I/Zygote  : Preloading resources...
I/Zygote  : Number of total Classes to prelaod: 2309
I/Zygote  : Classes to load for thread1 0~830
I/Zygote  : Classes to load for thread2 831~2308
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.InputQueue$FinishedCallback
I/DEBUG   : !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 4403
I/dumpstate: begin
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 63% free 956K/2560K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$2
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$3
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$4
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.animation.ValueAnimator$5
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 44% free 1439K/2560K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 27% free 1870K/2560K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.ViewRootImpl$3
V/BluetoothAudioGateway.cpp: classInitNative
V/BT HSHFP: classInitNative
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 10% free 2312K/2560K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 8% free 2361K/2560K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 2982K/3203K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.content.res.Resources$1
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 2% free 3659K/3715K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 2% free 4027K/4099K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 5049K/5187K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libwebcore.so)
D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libchromium_net.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 1% free 6325K/6339K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 2% free 7019K/7107K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 279 resources in 604ms.
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 31 resources in 7ms.
I/Zygote  : !@End of preloadResources()
D/TextLayoutCache: Using debug level = 0 - Debug Enabled = 0
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.EdgeGlow
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$DatabaseReentrantLock
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.AudioManager$2
I/dalvikvm: threadid=6: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
D/MtpDeviceJNI: register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
I/dalvikvm: threadid=6: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
I/dalvikvm: threadid=6: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.media.IRemoteControlClientDispatcher$Stub
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 lsof using binary lsof : lsof 
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$Blink
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$EasyEditSpanController
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$InputContentType
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$InputMethodState
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.widget.TextView$TextAlign
E/PhonePolicy: Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 308K, 4% free 8526K/8835K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.os.Power
V/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp: classInitNative
V/BluetoothService.cpp: classInitNative
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.text.TextDirectionHeuristics$CharCount
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.text.method.WordIterator$1
W/Zygote  : Class not found for preloading: android.view.InputHandler
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 831 classes in 1146ms.
I/System  : Loaded time zone names for  in 312ms (309ms in ICU)
I/System  : Loaded time zone names for en_US in 93ms (89ms in ICU)
I/System  : Loaded time zone names for it_IT in 101ms (97ms in ICU)
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 977K, 10% free 9650K/10627K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
I/Zygote  : ...preloaded 1478 classes in 1495ms.
I/Zygote  : !@EndofpreloadClasses()
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 327K, 12% free 9360K/10627K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 13% free 9339K/10627K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 13% free 9339K/10627K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm: System server process 4440 has been created
I/Zygote  : Accepting command socket connections
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020003 (t=1 e=3) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020001 (t=1 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020001 (t=1 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 13% free 9750K/11143K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 84ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
I/sysproc : !@beginofsystem_init1()
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020005 (t=1 e=5) in package 0 (error -75)
I/sysproc : Entered system_init()
I/sysproc : ServiceManager: 0x4c24d3c8
D/SensorService: nuSensorService starting...
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f5 (t=1 e=501) in package 0 (error -75)
I/AKMD2   : open_accelerometer
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f5 (t=1 e=501) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0201f4 (t=1 e=500) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020001 (t=1 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020004 (t=1 e=4) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020007 (t=1 e=7) in package 0 (error -75)
I/PackageParser: com.orange.authentication.simcard.permission: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001b (t=1 e=27) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001b (t=1 e=27) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f040001 (t=3 e=1) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001d (t=1 e=29) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f040000 (t=3 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020007 (t=1 e=7) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 168K, 13% free 10138K/11591K, paused 23ms+3ms, total 60ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02025f (t=1 e=607) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02032c (t=1 e=812) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02032f (t=1 e=815) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02022c (t=1 e=556) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 215K, 13% free 10473K/11975K, paused 37ms+2ms, total 55ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02022c (t=1 e=556) in package 0 (error -75)
I/SensorService: K3DH Acceleration Sensor
I/SensorService: AK8975 Magnetic field Sensor
I/SensorService: AK8975 Orientation Sensor
I/SensorService: CM3663 Light Sensor
I/SensorService: CM3663 Proximity Sensor
I/SensorService: K3G Gyroscope Sensor
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0204f6 (t=1 e=1270) in package 0 (error -75)
I/RemoteDesktopService: RemoteDesktopService started (pid=4440)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0204f6 (t=1 e=1270) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0204f6 (t=1 e=1270) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f110062 (t=16 e=98) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f110062 (t=16 e=98) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 259K, 13% free 10749K/12295K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
D/SensorService: nuSensorService thread starting...
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02000c (t=1 e=12) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001a (t=1 e=26) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0203c1 (t=1 e=961) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0203c1 (t=1 e=961) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f03003b (t=2 e=59) in package 0 (error -75)
I/PackageParser: com.monotype.android.font.helvneuelt: compat added android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 252K, 13% free 11009K/12551K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 43ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
D/su      : su invoked. 
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020004 (t=1 e=4) in package 0 (error -75)
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 sqlite3 using binary sqlite3 : sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db pragma user_version; select * from system; select * from secure; 
E/su      : exec failed with 2: No such file or directory 
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 241K, 12% free 11274K/12807K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 26ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020332 (t=1 e=818) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020334 (t=1 e=820) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020334 (t=1 e=820) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020334 (t=1 e=820) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020009 (t=1 e=9) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02001d (t=1 e=29) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020333 (t=1 e=819) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f10004b (t=15 e=75) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02035d (t=1 e=861) in package 0 (error -75)
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 netcfg using binary netcfg : netcfg 
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020319 (t=1 e=793) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020319 (t=1 e=793) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 294K, 13% free 11541K/13127K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 53ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020331 (t=1 e=817) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020328 (t=1 e=808) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020328 (t=1 e=808) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020328 (t=1 e=808) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02014e (t=1 e=334) in package 0 (error -75)
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 280K, 12% free 11809K/13383K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 45ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0e004d (t=13 e=77) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0e004e (t=13 e=78) in package 0 (error -75)
I/BootTime: Prefetch Time Taken:1050
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 iptables using binary iptables : iptables -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 ip6tables using binary ip6tables : ip6tables -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 iptables using binary iptables : iptables -t nat -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 iptables using binary iptables : iptables -t raw -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 ip6tables using binary ip6tables : ip6tables -t raw -L -nvx 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 wpa_cli using binary wpa_cli : wpa_cli list_networks 
E/su      : exec failed with 2: No such file or directory 
D/VoldCmdListener: asec list
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 cat using binary cat : cat /data/system/packages.xml 
D/su      : su invoked. 
D/su      : Allowing shell. 
D/su      : 2000 /system/bin/dumpstate executing 0 cat using binary cat : cat /proc/4403/maps 
I/dumpstate: done
I/ServiceManager: service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
I/ServiceManager: service 'SecTVOutService' died
F/libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 4423 (BootAnimation)
D/BootAnimation: SurfaceFlinger died, exiting...
F/libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 4440 (system_server)
I/ServiceManager: service 'sensorservice' died
I/DEBUG   : unexpected waitpid response: n=4440, status=00000009
I/DEBUG   : ptrace detach from 4440 failed: No such process
I/DEBUG   : debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
I/DEBUG   : debuggerd: Mar  7 2013 21:50:41
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you disable hardware composer with `setprop debug.hwc.force_gpu 1`?  (Note this is Samsung-specific; see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/samsung_slsi/exynos5/+/jb-mr2-release/libhwc/hwc.cpp .)

Comment: How can I disable that? What side effects will it bring?

Comment: You disable it with the setprop command.  Get a shell on the device, stop it with `stop`, issue the `setprop debug.hwc.force_gpu 1`, then restart it with `start` and see what happens.  If HWC is disabled, surfaceflinger will use GLES composition instead.

Comment: I don't why, but the problem seems to be gone... I don't have any freeze at startup, now. I'll be back in case they restart, thanks for now